# How to split heterogeneous array according to a condition in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Trying to split numpy array based on condition. The filter must take a split_column and its split_value and split the array into two parts, one containing the sub-array all rows <= split_value on the given split_column.

i.e. Given,

```
 a = np.array([[5, 'hi', 23],
               [4, 'we', 15],
               [3, 'me', 10],
               [2, 'be', 67],
               [1, 'it', 100]])

split_column = 0
split_value = 3
```

Expected output is

```
     [[3, 'me', 10],
      [2, 'be', 67],
      [1, 'it', 100]]
```

I tried this solution `a[a[:, split_column] <= split_value]` but it works only if all elements are numeric.

For mixed types in the numpy array (as shown above), I get

**TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'**

Using str() as in `a[a[:, split_column] <= str(split_value)]` isn't a solution because 10 <= 3 becomes true which isn't correct. For column(1), I need str compare but for the other columns it should be numeric compare.

How could we do this in numpy or do we have to iterate through all elements checking types before compare?

Comment: `a.dtype` is a string, right?  List was mixed, but not the array. Print `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the *columns* into desired `type` using `numpy.array.astype`:

```
a[a[:,0].astype(int) <= 3]
array([['3', 'me', '10'],
       ['2', 'be', '67'],
       ['1', 'it', '100']], dtype='<U11')
```